# Javascript to compute max width and height for a nested HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote the following code to give an HTML element max width/height in its parent container.
I think I address the box model issues but I am wondering if anyone can see issues and or shortcomings.

Are there other solutions out there that accomplish this? I want to make sure I didn't re-invent the wheel.

```
function heightBuffer(control) {
    return parseInt((control.outerHeight(true)) - control.height());
}

function widthBuffer(control) {
    return parseInt((control.outerWidth(true)) - parseInt(control.width()));
}

function MaxHeightInParent(control, minHeight, controlHeightsToSubtract) {
    var h = parseInt(control.parent().height()) - heightBuffer(control);
    if (controlHeightsToSubtract != null)
        $.each(controlHeightsToSubtract, function(index, value) {
            h = h - parseInt(value.outerHeight(true));
        });

    if (minHeight != null && h < minHeight) h = minHeight;
    control.height(0);
    control.css('min-height', h);
}

function MaxWidthInParent(control, minWidth, controlWidthsToSubtract) {
    var w = parseInt(control.parent().width()) - widthBuffer(control);
    if (controlWidthsToSubtract != null)
        $.each(controlWidthsToSubtract, function(index, value) {
            w = w - parseInt(value.outerWidth(true));
        });
    if (minWidth != null && w < minWidth) w = minWidth;
    control.width(0);
    control.css('min-width', w);
}
```

Note controlHeightsToSubtract / controlWidthsToSubtract are if you wish to pass an array of controls that share the containing element with the element you are attempting to maximize in Height/Width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is

```
parseInt((control.outerHeight(true)) - control.height());
```

supposed to achieve?

The result of `-` is always going to be a number, so what this does is convert the number to a string and back to a number.  This can only lose precision and waste time.

Similarly, the use of parseInt on the first argument is also unnecessary

```
parseInt(control.parent().height()) - heightBuffer(control)
```

since

```
"4" - 1 === 3
```

In fact, the automatic conversion that `-` does is better than that done by `parseInt` since `parseInt` falls back to octal on some interpreters but not others.

```
"10"             - 1 === 9
parseInt("10")   - 1 === 9
"0x10"           - 1 === 15
parseInt("0x10") - 1 === 15
"010"            - 1        // throws reliably
parseInt("010")  - 1 === 7  // on some and 9 on others
```

so I'd get rid of all the uses of `parseInt` as an operand to `-`.

You seem to be setting `min-height` but the method is called `MaxHeight`.  That confuses me.

When you change the CSS

```
control.css('min-height', h)
```

you might want to specify units as in

```
control.css('min-height', h + "px")
```

I'm not sure how you're handling the widths of margins and borders on the controls.  Is that important to you?